# Change <p> css style based on text length using plain javaScript

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, innerhtml, getelementsbyclassname

I would like to style a `<p>` dependant on the amount of text it contains ; 
using plain - vanila javaScript {no external library} 
+ *of course css* & html 4.1 for use in pre 29 FireFox. 
Using 1 : [Change an element's class with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript/196038#196038) - for the way to reference the  html element `getElementById("MyElement")` ... 
and adapting : [How to detect when multiple lines are occurring in a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13644930/how-to-detect-when-multiple-lines-are-occurring-in-a-div) `ele.innerHTML.length >= 70` to my specific needs. 
I cannot get http://jsfiddle.net/positive_x/HeCj7/ to work.
In that jsfiddle , I am trying to use the first way to prove - out & learn the algorithm ; 
 
**html + css & javaScript**  in the jsfiddle . net / positive_x / HeCj7 /

```
<aside>
    <p>This is a plain - old paragraph.</p>
    <p id='p_id1'>This is the p_id1 (blue) p</p>
    <p id='p_id2'>This is the p_id2 (really l o n g ___ R E D ) paragraph . </p>
    <p class='styletest'>This is a short class= p</p>
    <p class='styletest'>This is other class= (really long _ R E D) paragraph .</p>
</aside>
<script>window.onload = style_byID_Blue_short_p;</script>
```

/* css  in jsfiddle */

```
.blue {color: #117;}
.green {color: #161;}
.red  {color: #511;}
```

/* javascript in jsfiddle
    TESTing 1 getElementById('idname') way */

```
function style_byID_Blue_short_p () {
    var textIn = document.getElementById('p_id1');
    var txtLen = textIn.innerHTML.length;
    if( txtLen<30 ){
        textIn.className += ' blue'; //turn it blue
        alert('here is style_byID_Blue_short_p that IDS blue!'); //for testing
    } else {
        textIn.style.color = #511; //turn it red
        alert('style_byID_Blue_short_p that is red.'); //for testing
    }
}
```

Additionally, I *really* need to apply the styling to a number of `<p>` 
via the `getElementsByClass("myclassname")` that is in the second part of the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/positive_x/HeCj7/) shown in the jsfiddle itself.
The required array nomenclature has me intimidated ; ( 
; so I attempted the first _ simpler portion *first*.
As a `copy-&-paste` coder , I could use your help.
Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, besides the tons of syntax and spelling errors and not placing CSS colors in quotes (you should really use the browser console and JSHint on jsfiddle), your problem has to do with the fact that your handlers aren't applied properly.

You need to use `addEventHandler` to make sure the event handlers are attached after your javascript is parsed. If you had checked the console, you'd have seen that they are undefined at load time, hence nothing runs.

Instead of:

```
<script>
    window.onload = style_byClass_RED_Long;
</script>
```

do

```
window.addEventListener('onload', style_byClass_RED_Long);
```

and put that in your javascript. However, that might not work in a fiddle, so just call your functions at the bottom of your javascript and it should produce your results. For all practical purposes, it should be the same thing as using `onload`.

here's your fiddle fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/HeCj7/9/

also, `getElementsByClassName` returns an `array` of elements, not a single one. You'll need to enumerate the elements and change each one separately. In your code, i simply changed it so that it refers to the first element only, which means your second `<p>` with that class will remain unstyled.

Comment: i added a link to a fixed one

Comment: me: TODO implement a for loop to step - through all of the `<p class='styletest'>` referenced by `getElementsByClassName('styletest')` & get-rid-of the test alert -- In the second "desired" portion of the jsfiddle.

Comment: After a small amount of study ; i like your solution in the jsfiddle itself of invoking the functions right - in -the -js "style_byClass_RED_Long();
style_byID_Blue_short_p();" Rather than in the html . Makes sense due to the idea that this routine's purpose is to style the <p> s based on the length of text contaiined in them.

Comment: **Works** _thanks again_ @IvyLynx  Updated with the `for (var i=0; i< textIn.length; i = i+1)  { ...` & `variableNameS[i]`  to handle the array returned by `getElementsBtClassName` ;  here : [http://jsfiddle.net/positive_x/qsStc/](http://jsfiddle.net/positive_x/qsStc/)